# Is it possible to hide individual CheckBoxes in a CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have a `CheckedListBox` called `clbExample`. I've added items to it like so:

```
public void AddStuff()
{
    clbExample.Items.Add("Item1");
    clbExample.Items.Add("Item2");
    clbExample.Items.Add("Item3");
    clbExample.Items.Add("Item4");
    clbExample.Items.Add("Item5");
}
```

Now, say I want to completely hide the Checkbox next to "Item3" while still displaying the text. I don't want to disable the CheckBox either (I have no control over this, it's just the task I was given).
Is this possible to do? I've been looking into overriding the draw events and doing that all myself, which isn't particularly difficult in a standard scenario, but I do not see how I could use this to hide a particular CheckBox since that property appears to always be set to "Normal" for a `CheckedListBox` according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.drawmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).